# Derive DFT of $x[2n]$

Tags: dft

Question is to find DFT, $G_7(k)$ of $g_7(n)$ = $x(2n)$.

**For purpose of illustration only,** we can assume that $x(n)$ can be represented by envelope shown in corresponding figure.
[image]

Shown in Figure Below, is solution to this problem.
[image]

But, I am unable to understand this Solution.

If anyone can help me understand this solution, I will be very thankful.

Comment: How many points DFT? $N$, $2N$, $N/2$? And in the figure, is it $x(n)$ or $x(2n)$ that you're showing ?

Comment: Which part you did not understand?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what part exactly of the solution you didn't understand.

The purpose of the posed question is to show the spectral effects of signal downsampling, in this case by a factor of 2.

The original discrete signal is $x[n]$ (whose DTFT is $X(e^{j\omega})$), with a length of N samples, and the downsampled signal (by a factor of 2) is $g_7[n]=x[2n]$, so $g_7[n]$ is made from the even samples of $x[n]$, with a total length of N/2 samples.

The first experssion of the solution is simply the DFT (by definition) of $g_7[n]$. The solution then proceeds to some series manipulation, then uses the DTFT-derived definition of DFT to show the final expression.

The final expression of the solution shows that downsampling the signal by a factor of 2 produces a double-frequency image of the original signal in the frequency domain. This alludes to the importance of anti-aliasing filtering prior to signal downsampling.

Comment: @ARK, please consider choosing my answer. Thanks.